# LWJGL - OpenGL context gets lost in shutdown hook

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, shutdown-hook

I'm currently working with Java and LWJGL 3 and I'm writing some wrappers for stuff like vertex array objects, vertex buffer objects, etc.
Now it's a good habit to delete these objects before program exit, so I created a shutdown hook which is supposed to do the clean up.

But when I call an OpenGL function inside of the shutdown hook I get an illegal state exception which says that an OpenGL context has not been initialized.

I've written a test program which reproduces this behaviour:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GLFW.glfwInit();
    long window = GLFW.glfwCreateWindow(100, 100, "", 0, 0);

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            GL15.glDeleteBuffers(0);
            GLFW.glfwTerminate();
        }
    });

    while (!GLFW.glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        GLFW.glfwPollEvents();
    }
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No GLCapabilities instance set for the current thread. Possible solutions:
a) Call GL.createCapabilities() after making a context current in the current thread.
b) Call GL.setCapabilities() if a GLCapabilities instance already exists for the current context.
at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL.getCapabilities(GL.java:241)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.nglDeleteBuffers(GL15.java:152)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.glDeleteBuffers(GL15.java:178)
at core.Main$1.run(Main.java:11)
```

Does anyone know why the context gets destroyed automatically?

If you need any extra information just say so.

Comment: What is the purpose of the shutdown hook? Is `glfwWindowShouldClose` not good enough?

Comment: Note, that OpenGL contexts are bound to one specific thread. Since you are spawning a new thread you'll have to bind the context before using.

Comment: @NicolBolas no, I want to decouple this interface from other classes, so I don't want to call a disposeAll method or something.

Comment: @RagingRabbit: I don't see any "decoupling", since the destruction is still defined within `main`. Whatever that shutdown hook is going to do could be done just as effectively as a function that `main` calls when the loop is done. In what way is that not sufficiently "decoupled"?

Comment: @BDL thanks for pointing that out! Can you post that as an answer, please?

Comment: @NicolBolas this is just a demonstration of the problem, normally the shutdown hook is added inside of the interface by using a static block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A OpenGL context is always associated with one thread (or with no thread). Functions can only be called on a particular context from the thread that the context is bound to.

Since the shutdown hook starts a new thread, you have to bind the OpenGL context to that thread before issuing any commands.